# Mounting an encrypted server

Tags: 14.04, server, mount, encryption

Everything I've found on this is either how to encrypt a mounted drive, or not to do with servers.

I have an ubuntu 14.04 server which I am trying to mount as a network share onto my 14.04 desktop so I can use something other than vim or emacs to edit files.

I've connected to the server through ssh, through the terminal and nautilus, so can easily copy and paste files across. But I can't access any files directly through programs such as PyCharm.

I've mounted the server to /mnt/nfs/home.

But the only files which are accessible are 'Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop' and 'README.txt' - both seem to be corrupt, or empty. I assume this is because I have encrypted the server.

So what is the process for mounting an encrypted server?

Edit:

At the moment I'm trying to mount with sshfs.

however `sudo sshfs user@server:/home /mnt/nfs/home`

Just converts the directory /home at /mnt/nfs into a binary file.

Comment: So you're not doing a regular ssh login (which would work), just trying to "mount with sshfs"... does it even support encrypted homes?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your home directory is encrypted. When you log in graphically, your home directory is decrypted automatically. This does not happen with ssh.

You have to run ecryptfs-mount-private AFTER logging in via ssh.

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd ~
ls
```

You will also have a problem is you try to use ssh keys. See http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/Ecryptfs#SSH and [Why is ecryptfs only mounting private home directory over ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165608/why-is-ecryptfs-only-mounting-private-home-directory-over-ssh) and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1332820

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question. I have no issue sshing into the server, accessing and writing files, I do so very regularly. similarly I can connect via nautilus and copy/paste files etc. I just can't mount the home drive on the server onto my desktop which causes issues for programs like PyCharm.

Comment: because you home directory is encrypted . This is what "the only files which are accessible are 'Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop' and 'README.txt' " means. Did you run the commands I gave you and if so what if any error messages did you get? Did you read any of the additional information I gave you ?